# Azure VM backup best practice

Tags: sql-server, backup, azure-vm

I have a customer who has just lifted-n-shifted their 1TB SQL Server 2008 R2 production, and QA servers (2 servers) to Azure IaaS from a small cloud provider.

What is the best practice for backups?

I am more used to Azure SaaS with encrypted, centralised backup storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use manual backup or better Azure SQL vm backup.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/backup-restore#backup-and-restore-options

here you can find microsoft guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/tutorial-sql-backup